# How does grass r.viewshed take into account the Earth curvature?

Tags: grass-gis, wgs84, viewshed, ellipsoid, curvature

Up to now I always had to do such analysis in a local Cartesian Coordinate System and on relatively small datasets, but today, I want to compute a [viewshed analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewshed_analysis) on a large raster DEM which is given in [ESPG:4326](https://epsg.org/crs_4326/WGS-84.html?sessionkey=h59r0z5jrn) (WGS84) (lon, lat in degrees units) using [GRASS GIS](https://grass.osgeo.org/) [r.viewshed](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.viewshed.html).
In the documentation of this function, I can read this for the flag `-c`:

> **-c**
> Consider the curvature of the earth (current ellipsoid)

I don't really now from that definition, if what they call the "current ellipsoid" is the one which is defined by the embedded projection of my loaded raster or the one defined when creating the grass project workspace (I'm totally new to that software)? This doesn't have much importance in my situation because both are the same but I'd like to know.

Then, I have the strong feeling that I may get into troubles, especially with long distances, with the fact that the DEM regular grid itself is given with (lon, lat) pixels expressed in degrees.

Hence my question;

Should I consider re-projecting the raster to a local cartographic plane or not, for both cases (with and without the `-c` flag) before running the [viewshed analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewshed_analysis)?

| Projection type | -c flag enable | -c flag disabled |
| --- | --- | --- |
| (*initial data*) WGS84 Geographic Coordinate System | A | B |
| Local Projected, Cartesian Coordinate System | C | D |

For which of the A, B, C or D cases does or doesn't it make sense to run a viewshed analysis?

Comment: If you run `g.proj -w` in GRASS GIS, within your "location"/"mapset", it tells you the  ellipsoid of the projection definition of that particular "location" (i.e. GRASS GIS current data directory). There is not much mystery behind but feel free to suggest a better wording which I agree could be better.

Comment: The consideration of the curvature makes sense with larger viewsheds (say, regional ones) but not if they are local (say, within a city neighborhood). GRASS GIS can deal with both Geographic Coordinate Systems and Cartesian Coordinate Systems.

Comment: Unless you used the '-o' flag with `r.in.gdal`, your raster and your workspace CRS should be identical and on the same ellipsoid.

I think if you want to get familiar with the tool, its a good idea to also set up a workspace in an appropriate local projection and run some comparisons across the four scenarios above. Use r.import to reproject on the fly during import in that case, and please post an answer to your own question afterwards, especially if you find significant problems with any of the four scenarios.